# The child process exited normally with status 0

Tags: shell, ubuntu, child-process

Wherever I open a terminal and want to exit it, it keeps saying:

> The child process exited normally with status 0.

at the top of the terminal.

[image]

Before I even entered a command, and just want to "exit" the terminal.

When I click relaunch:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details ? How did you try to exit ?

Comment: Before I even entered a command, and just want to "exit" the terminal.

Comment: so -- the terminal is just the window. When you type "exit", you aren't telling the terminal to exit, you're telling the copy of bash (or whatever other shell or software's output is displayed inside the terminal) to exit; that copy of bash is "the child process" here.

Comment: That said, this question isn't really topical here (StackOverflow's focus being, as it is, strictly on software development and tools specific to that use; see the "unique to software development" phrasing in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic connected to the other clauses with "and", not "or"). In the future, you might consider [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for questions about using OS-provided software/tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right, I willl keep it in mind.

Answer (score 6):

**SOLVED**

It was due to a setting in my terminal profile -> command
"Hold terminal open when exit".

My bad.